# parse uniVerse hash / data files in R

Tags: r, universe

I have inherited a uniVerse database ([link to Rocketsoftware site](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/products/rocket-universe)) and would like to know if it's possible to read/parse the underlying data files (which I believe are hash tables?) into 'R'?

I'm aware there are `ODBC` drivers as well as `.NET` libraries, but I'm interested in parsing the files in `R` (if possible) without these drivers?

(I've searched and seen a few topics on parsing hash tables in Java and C#, but nothing in R yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a propriety format, so unless you want to reverse engineer it and re-implement in R that isn't the path forward. Also note that it isn't a single hash-table format either, aside from the standard modulo and bucket sizes, there are several different formats you'll encounter.

If you don't want work with any of the native APIs of the database to read the data, you can issue database commands that will dump it to CSV or XML flat files. Take a look into the RetrieVe query language manuals to learn more.

Comment: thanks. I was hoping someone had done the "reverse engineering and re-implement in R" bit already, but it sounds like I'll have to use a different approach.